# Looking for lightweight responsive CSS framework supporting max width 968px

Tags: css, frameworks, responsive-design

I have been looking into using a css framework for my next project. I would like to use a css framework that is responsive and should have a max-width: 968px also it should be lightweight system (only grids), not requiring buttons, navigation etc. Are there any recommendations on css frameworks that I should use, the problem that I seem to come across is that the frameworks are generally set to a predefined size such as 960px and something seems to break whenever I make changes to support this 968px size (it may just be my lack of experience of using frameworks and lack of understanding).

I am looking for recommendations on which css framework to use, and also any help on setting it up for the max width 968px;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone is going to down vote please can you at least leave a reason, it can only help users to improve questions that are asked.

Comment: This is what is called a "shopping" questions and those are considered Not-constructive. Have you read the [faq]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any responsive platforms that run the (old) 960px wide standard.  Every platform I've seen is somewhere around 1140px.

That said however, you could use [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/) and modify it to be 968px wide.

Columnal is very light weight, supports columns within columns, and the class names are pleasant to work with. (though I do a find and replace and get rid of all _'s and change them to -'s).  All you would need to do is change the `max-width:` value on the class `.row` in the `columnal.css`.

**Note***** that I have tested changing `.row` to `968px` on one of my personal sites which uses Columnal, no matter than value I inserted (600, 800, 960, 968, 1140(default), 1200, 1300) it always worked.

You can test this yourself by visiting the site linked below and using chrome developer tools, find a div with class of row, and change the max-width value to whatever you please.

http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, looks good to me. :)